# Will Jira complain if I set the Resolution date to a date before the creation via direct DB write?

Tags: database, jira, corruption

Some colleagues were using an Excel file to keep track of some issues, and they have decided to switch to a better system, asking me to setup a Jira project for them and to import all the tickets. A way or the other I have done everything, but the resolution date is now wrong, because it's the one of when I ran the script to import them into Jira. They would like to have the original one, so that they can know when an issue was really fixed. Unfortunately there's no way to change it from Jira's interface, so I have to access the DB directly. The command, for the record, is like:

```
update jiraissue
set RESOLUTIONDATE = "2015-02-16 14:48:40"
where pkey = "OV001-1";
```

Now, low-level writes to a database in general are dangerous, and I am wondering whether there can be any risks. Our test server is not available right now, so I'd have to work directly on the production one. One thing I had seen on our test server is that this seemed to work, except that JQL queries such as

```
resolved < 2015-03-20
```

are wrong because they still use the old Resolution date. Clearly, I have to reindex; but I'm wondering whether it is safe. Does Jira perform some consistency checks? Like, verifying that a ticket is solved after it is created. In my case, since I have modified the resolution date but not the creation, it is a clear inconsistency. Will Jira complain about this? Is there the risk to corrupt the DB? And if I also modify the creation date, do I have to watch out for other things?

We are using Jira 5.2.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have access to the test server again, and I have tried it. I have modified all the `RESOLUTIONDATE` fields I had to fix, and when I reloaded the page the new date was there. Jira didn't complain about anything. I reindexed the server, so that queries yield correct results, and I saw no issues. Then I even ran the integrity checks (Administration -> System -> Integrity Checker), and no error was found.
Finally I did the same on the production server, and again everything is running fine.

I can therefore conclude that the operation is not dangerous at all, and it can be done safely.